# TikTok-like scrolling with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have videos on my webpage displayed in a scrollable list, where each video is covering the whole screen, like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Videos</title>
  <style>
    body {
      background-color: #090909;
    }

    .video-box {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
    }

    .video-box video {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      padding: 8px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      max-height: 100vh;
      max-width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <section class="videos">
    <div class="video-box">
      <video preload="none" poster="vert1.png" autoplay muted loop playsinline>
        <source src="vert1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
    </div>
    <div class="video-box">
      <video preload="none" poster="vert2.png" autoplay muted loop playsinline>
        <source src="vert2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
    </div>
    <div class="video-box">
      <video preload="none" poster="vert1.png" autoplay muted loop playsinline>
        <source src="vert1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
    </div>
    <div class="video-box">
      <video preload="none" poster="vert2.png" autoplay muted loop playsinline>
        <source src="vert2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

The missing piece for my implementation is to make the videos snap, like in eg. TikTok or YouTube Shorts. I tried implementing it with JavaScript with [fullPage.js](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) but found the additional effort of putting scripts into webpage code problematic. Is this implementation possible with just HTML and CSS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this specific purpose `page-snap-*` [CSS properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Scroll_Snap/Basic_concepts) were created.

To make pages snap in the example, just two additional CSS properties have to be added:

```html
  <style>
    html /* IMPORTANT: scroll-snap-type won't work with body selector, so replace it with html */ {
      background-color: #090909;
      scroll-snap-type: y mandatory; /* Define snapping behavior. "y" indicates vertical behavior, "mandatory" won't allow the user to stay in-between two pages. */
    }

    .video-box {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      scroll-snap-align: start; /* Define snapping target. Can also be "center" or "end". */
    }

    .video-box video {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      padding: 8px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      max-height: 100vh;
      max-width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
```